# How to display custom image on custom created admin menu tab?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-panel

How to display custom image on custom created admin menu tab?

[image]

like Dashboard image ,need to display the image on left medu tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add admin area css file to your custom module in view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<head>
     <css src="Vendor_Module::css/adminhtml.css"/>
</head>
```

in your css file add like,

```
.admin__menu #menu-vendor-module-menu.level-0 > a:before {
    content: url('../images/custom-image.png');
    height: 32px;
}
```

path as adminhtml/web/css/adminhtml.css

vendor-menu is your cusom medu id which mentioned in menu.xml
place your custom image in adminhtml/web/image/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this article: https://vky.co.in/magento-2-custom-module-menu-admin-panel/

Like this:

```
START TO ADD CSS IN THE HEAD ADMIN PANEL
Create Vky/Core/view/adminhtml/web/css/vky.less
.admin__menu .item-vky > a:before {
    content: '' !important;
    background: url(../images/vky_logo.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: 35px auto;
    height:40px !important;
}
```